# Manipulating datastore data after loading

Tags: sencha-touch-2, dataview, datastore

I have a backend that returns some JSON data that is used by my datastore through an ajax proxy. The data is then displayed in a dataview. What I need to do is perform some transformation on the received data on client side before it is displayed by the dataview.

I tried various approaches and settled on attaching a handler to the datastore's `load` event:

```
Ext.getStore('MyStore').on('load', function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {         
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        var e = records[i];
        e.data.myField = "constantPrefix" + e.data.myField;
    }
});
```

The handler fires and records are changed correctly.

**Problem is, the dataview still shows unchanged data. Is the whole approach correct? If so, why's it not working; if not - how would you achieve that?**

Below is the dataview code:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.MyDataView', {
extend : 'Ext.DataView',
xtype : 'my-dataview',

config : {      
    store : 'MyStore',
    baseCls : Ext.os.deviceType === 'Phone' ? 'my-dataview-phone' : 'my-dataview-tablet',
    mode: 'MULTI',
    allowDeselect: true,
    selectedCls: 'tick-visible',        
    triggerEvent: 'itemdoubletap',


    itemTpl : [
            '<img class="my-photo my-dataview-photo" src="',                        
            '{myField}"></img>'             
        ].join('')              
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
 e.data.myField = "constantPrefix" + e.data.myField;
```

use

```
var value = "constantPrefix" + e.get('myField');
e.set('myField', value);
```

[model.set()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set) is responsible to trigger necessary events, which the dataview does catch.

cheers, Oleg

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inform the store listeners about the modified fields. Try:

```
Ext.getStore('MyStore').afterEdit(e, ['myField']);
```

This has the advantage, that the dataview or grid will now show the fields as modified (with these red triangles in the field).